# Sql Anywhere 9 cannot access on Network

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

heres the situation, i have a windows 2008 enterprise server (brand new) so far the only thing installed on it out of the box is SQL Anywhere 9.0.2 and Mysql 5.1 its all setup and working i have transferred a database to the server and set it up as a service, however i cannot get a local or remote connection to the database to view tables, stored procs etc.

i have setup the windows Firewall to allow traffic into and out of the server on any port for that service but so far nothing has worked. According to Sybase's website 9.0.2 is supported on windows 2008, netstat shows no open connections except my RDP session.

I can however connect remotely and locally to the Mysql database.

am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local connections use shared memory and so won't be affected by the firewall. Which application have you tried to connect with? I'd be interested in your connection string from the same machine-connection. Usually I use the uid, pwd, eng, and dbf parameters and they are enough to make a connection.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the reply the only program i have attempted connections with so far is the Sybase utility that came with the server installation.

i have tried locally i.e. on the server and remotely on my desktop and neither seem to connect. there may be a connection string sybase is using but i am not aware of it or adding anything extra to the connection string.

thanks
kris

Answer (score 0):

You need at least UID, PWD, and ENG to connect to a server locally, and remote clients need to add "LINKS=tcpip" as well. If just adding LINKS doesn't work (since clients will be using UDP broadcasts, which may be filtered by the firewall), you might need to specify the hostname, like: "LINKS=tcpip(host=myhostname)".

Answer (score 0):

OK, the service is defined.
But is it started?